# Laravel, HTML: insert separate template in Main-Template

Tags: html, laravel

Im currently learning laravel.
Im familiar HTML & Javascript, PHP.

Im planing to Include a File 'Page-Register.html' into the basic File 'APP-Page.html'

```
<a href="/reg.html">Registration</a>
<div id="Here-comes-Registration-template-if-link-is-clicked"></div>
```

if I click on the Registration link. But so far, Im not quiet understand laravel - I'm not familiar with the approach by single-paging (if this is the right term?).

I do not want to be redirected to a new individual page "app-page.php/reg".

What is the best approach? What term I have to look for?

Thanksalot

Answer (score 0):

If you want the registration page to appear on the current page instead of opening in a new tab or window, you will have to hide the page and then show it with a button. You can do this in Javascript. Here is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
         #register {
         width: 100%;
         padding: 50px 0;
         text-align: center;
         background-color: lightblue;
         margin-top: 20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Register</button>
      <div id="register">
         Registration code is displayed here
      </div>
      <script>
         var x = document.getElementById("register");
         x.style.display = "none";
         function myFunction() {
           if (x.style.display === "none") {
             x.style.display = "block";
           } else {
             x.style.display = "none";
           }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example that hides the register button once the section is displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
         #register-section {
         width: 100%;
         padding: 50px 0;
         text-align: center;
         background-color: lightblue;
         margin-top: 20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="myFunction()" id="reg_button">Register</button>
      <div id="register_section">
          <br>
          <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
          <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit">
      </div>
      <script>
         var x = document.getElementById("register_section");
         var y = document.getElementById("reg_button");
         x.style.display = "none";
         function myFunction() {
           if (x.style.display === "none") {
             x.style.display = "block";
             y.style.display = "none";
           } else {
             x.style.display = "none";
           }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here you can see the code working: https://jsfiddle.net/yf35627s/

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Laravel blade documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade - What you want is to include blade templates into other blade templates.

You can also include PHP files, but if you're trying to learn Laravel: try blade templating.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, i found it...

Its called "generics Layout".

Perfect! Sorry, I didnt know the basic approach / term to describe the princip